# Microwave to optical photon conversion- relation with long distance communication

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

I am reading a paper on microwave to optical photon conversion (https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.99.063830) and there the authors are saying-

Long-distance communication using microwave photons requires the channel to be cooled at cryogenic temperatures, however using microwave to optical upconverter would resolve the issue of cooling.

I do not understand why would changing the frequency of light help maintain the coherence of light. It would be nice if someone could explain.

Comment: You should post the paper in question. But I would guess they say that because there is a large background of microwave photons from blackbody radiation (aka heat) at ambient temperature (20 C).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It makes sense. I have added the link to the paper.